# perl - searching in list of objects which are an accessor of another object

Tags: perl, oop, moose

I am a Perl-OO beginner and I am encountering a design-challenge. I hope you can give me some hints to get to an elegant solution. I am working with Mouse Object System here.

For a minimal example lets say I have a User-Object. A user has a name.

```
package User;
use Mouse;    

has "name" => (
   is        => "rw",
   isa       => "Str|Undef",
);
```

Then I have a User-Cache-Object, which gets a list of all Users (from an LDAP-Server). You can say this is a "has-a" Relationship between the User Cache and the User.

```
package UserCache;
use Mouse;    

has "users" => (
   is        => 'rw',
   isa       => 'ArrayRef|Undef',
   default   => sub { [] },
);
```

I store this list of Users as an Array of User-Objects in the accessor of the User-Cache.

```
 my $cache = UserCache->new();

 foreach my $entry ( $ldap->searchGetEntries() ) { 
      my $user = User->new();
      $user->name($entry->get_value('userdn'));
      push @{ $cache->users }, $user;
 }
```

Now this is where my Problem comes in. If I want to find a User-Object with specific attributes (e.g. a User named John), I have to loop over this whole Array of User-Objects and query each object for its name. When given a list of names, this gets a really inefficient process.

```
foreach my $user ( @{ $cache->users } ) {
      if ( $user->name eq 'John' ) {
           #do something with John
      }...
}
```

Is there a way of storing Lists of Objects in other Objects in a way, that I can efficently search? Like *$cache->get_users->get_name('John')* and that returns the object I need?

Comment: Actually, my answer gives you something else than what you ask for in your last sentence. To do `$cache->get_users->get_name('John')`, you would have to create another class, where `get_users` returns an instance of that class. It would then have to have a `get_name` method. That would in turn have to look up the names. Either by iterating over all the users every time, essentially abstracting (hiding) the logic from the user, or by doing it once and caching/indexing it the way I described in my answer. It's probably a question of interface design which one you prefer. I'd go with my `find`.

Comment: Why do you allow `undef` for your attributes? In case of the `users`, you even have a default. The `name` of the user can likely be `ro`, and then it's a String and stays a string and there's no need for allowing `undef`.

Comment: Your text says you're using Mouse, but your examples are using Moose. Which is it? They both exist.

Comment: I actually use Mouse, I think a typo caught me here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**. At least not universally. You can of course build indexes for common things. Or you could cache searches once you have done them.

Lookups are best implemented as hashes. Those could be attached to the UserCache object. Something like:

```
my @users = $cache->find( name => 'John' );
```

That would internally map to a hashref with search fields.

```
package UserCache;
#...

has _search_index => (
    is  => 'ro',
    isa => 'HashRef',
    default => sub { {} },
);
```

And the hash reference would look something like this:

```
{
    name => {
        John => [
            User->new( name => 'John', last_name => 'Smith' ),
            User->new( name => 'John', last_name => 'Wayne' ),
            User->new( name => 'John', last_name => 'Bon Jovi' ),
        ],
        James => [ ... ],
    },
    id => {
        # ...
    },
),
```

But again, you'd have to build those. So you need to do the lookup once. But I think the lookup should be done inside UserCache and stored there too.

```
sub find {
    my ($self, $key, $value) = @_;

    # get operation
    return @{ $self->_search_index->{$key}->{$value} } 
        if exists $self->_search_index->{$key}->{$value};

    # set operation
    foreach my $user ( @{ $self->users } ) {
        push @{ $self->_search_index->{$key}->{$value} }, $user
            if $user->$key eq $value
    }
    return @{ $self->_search_index->{$key}->{$value} } 
}
```

This is a very naive implementation and it doesn't support multiple lookups, but it's a start.

Note that if you have a lot of users and a lot of indexes, the data structure might become large.

To make it easier, [Moose's built-in traits](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native::Trait::Hash) might be helpful. If you want a stronger cache behavior, look at [CHI](http://p3rl.org/CHI).

Comment: CHI looks like a great place to start. Thank you very much for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 5):

You don't really have to write the `UserCache` class yourself. Instead, use [CHI](https://metacpan.org/pod/CHI) to cache users you want to cache under the key you want to use for lookups. If you want, you can wrap your cache class to abstract away from the specific cache implementation.

Also, you have this:

```
push @{ $cache->users }, $user;
```

where you leak implementation details. Instead, your `UserCache` object needs something like a `save_user` method so the code it uses does not depend on the implementation details.

```
$cache->save_user( $user );
```

For Moose objects, you get [Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native::Trait::Array](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native::Trait::Array); for Mouse, you get [MouseX::NativeTraits::ArrayRef](https://metacpan.org/pod/MouseX::NativeTraits::ArrayRef).

Comment: Thanks for the hint that I am leaking Implementation details. I completely overlooked this!

Comment: This is super useful, thank you!  I somehow missed this interesting question.